# Реализация кучи

Tags: c++, ос, heap

Говорят, что динамическая память в программе выделяется в куче, а локальные переменные - в стеке. Если с реализаций стека всё вроде бы понятно, то каким образом куча обычно реализована в ОС? Я знаю 3 известные реализации кучи: бинарная, биномиальная и куча Фибоначчи. Какая из них используется? Как `new` узнает приоритет значения, помещаемого в кучу? Понятно, что зависит от реализации, но хотелось бы услышать примеры для `linux` и `windows`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если что то называется кучей, это ещё не значит, что оно может быть биномиальной или бинарной кучей. Это может быть куча мусора.

Обычно это все устроено так. Приложение запрашивает у операционной системы большой кусок памяти, а потом уже встроенный менеджер памяти (который реализуется внутри stl/glibc/CRT), нарезает ее мелкими порциями. О большинства операционных систем сложно попросить ровно 2-4 байта памяти. Они обычно меньше 4-16 кб даже не выделяют.

На самом низком уровне в линуксе приложение не может попросить "ось, дай мне метр памяти". Там есть только специальный вызов [brk](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=brk&category=2&russian=0), который подвигает верхнюю границу памяти для процесса. То есть, у процесса есть область памяти с фиксированным началом и он может подвигать верхнюю границу. Что будет делать приложение с памятью в этой области - личное дело приложения. Хотя ещё есть mmap, но это уже отдельная тема.

В Windows есть [Heap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapcreate) который достаточно похож на обычный malloc/free.

> Какая из них используется?

Самое смешное, что куча для памяти обычно реализуется на базе связанного списка. Можно изучить код с сайта [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-memory/sidefile.html), что бы понять, как устроен malloc/free.

Если хочется понять глубже как это устроено, то можно поизучать различные реализации менеджеров памяти

- [tmalloc](https://github.com/mkaguilera/tmalloc)
- [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/)

Можно на [хабре почитать](https://habr.com/post/270009/).

---

P.S.

> Если с реализаций стека всё вроде бы понятно

боюсь, что нет:)

Comment: почему тогда называется куча, если это связанный список?

Comment: @kernel Вот именно потому в *нормальных* книгах по алгоритмам и структурам данных есть **пирамида**, а не **куча** - чтоб не путали теплое с мягким...

Comment: @kernel потому что все красивые слова закончились

Comment: @kernel, разберитесь в разнице между динамической памятью как абстракцией языка, и динамической памятью как инструментом ОС. Куча - это про первое.

Comment: @Harry в книгах по истории древнего Египта? в классической "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" - heap переводят как куча

Comment: @kernel Ну-ну.. хамить идите в другое место. Даже спорить не стану, Кнут или Кормен для вас - это не классика, там головой работать надо...

Comment: @kernel На самом в контексте С++ говорить, что "динамическая память в программе выделяется в куче, а локальные переменные - в стеке" некорректно. В стандарте ни стек, ни куча в этом контексте вообще не упоминаются. Есть static storage duration - хранится где-то до конца, automatic storage duration - хранится где-то и автоматически разрушается при выходе из области видимости, dynamic storage duration - создается и удаляется вручную посредством вызова new / delete, которые вызывают соотв. функцию аллокации. Все три могут запросто храниться на стеке или в куче.

Comment: @Harry, специально полез в книжный шкаф. Кнут не употребляет термина "куча", и уж тем более "пирамида". В то время, когда писался первый том, терминология еще не устоялась, так что в главе 2.5 о динамическом распределении памяти он говорит "область" и "блок". Книга Кормена с соавторами рассматривает кучи только в контексте сортировки (глава 7), но в начале главы он упоминает про "кучи" именно в контексте распределения памяти. Откуда вы взяли эти "пирамиды" и что это за "нормальные" книги? :-O Заинтриговали...

Comment: @KoVadim, говорить, что куча реализуется как связанный список, не совсем правильно. В список связываются только свободные области. Еще замечу, что кучи Windows не совсем аналог malloc. Функционал у них побольше, и кроме того, программа может владеть несколькими кучами.

Comment: @freim Кнут лично употребляет heap :), а переводится это в томе 3 как пирамида (в разделе о пирамидальной сортировке). Вы взгляните на начало дискуссии - речь идет об *алгоритмах и структурах данных*, а не о динамическом распределении памяти. И именно это я и пишу - пирамида, а не куча. В применении к структуре данных. Перечитайте дискуссию еще раз - где я хоть раз говорил о распределении памяти?

Comment: @freim -  я знаю, я просто максимально упрощаю.